# Temporarily switch MySQL columns for readability?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that looks like this, with some more information

[image: Part of the database structure]

Basically, I'm collecting results from e-Sports games in this table. Now, when I read the data, I'm putting them in tables to see how each team performs. Unfortunately, sometimes the team I have selected is team1, sometimes team2.  Displaying this in a table really hurts the readability:

[image: Team matchup table]

I'd like to have the team I have selected always on the left side. If I'd just switch team1 and team2 in the code, other information (like team1_roster or team1_percent) would be assigned to the wrong team. Is there any way to do this without using complex inconvenient methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the query you currently use?

Comment: @juergend `SELECT * FROM matches WHERE (team1 = '".$_GET['name']."' OR team2 = '".$_GET['name']."') ORDER BY time DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the "change/switch" in whatever code *read* the SQL and/or *renders* the table based on the selected condition.

This is no fundamentally different than choosing the column coloring, except it works on the row and not individual cell. This can be written 'generically' outside of the rendering as well; if reading each row as a "pair of data" (each team info is a datum) and then simply swap the pairs based on condition before containing processing.

This change is merely about the view (or model passed to the view generation) and it should *not* affect the underlying data or column names therein.

If just handled in SQL it would be a "complex inconvenient" query because it is about transposing N columns based on a condition, which is not something SQL likes to express.